# Pandas-Python date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data set. I try to keep only the entries from a certain date range that I give. The probelm we have is that when the start and end date aren't in the dates of my date set, I take a key err exception.

```
Duration    Film    Deadline
1777         a      02/04/2018
1777         b      02/04/2018
1777         b      02/04/2018
942          b      03/04/2018
941          c      03/04/2018


  start_date = sys.argv[1]
  end_date = sys.argv[2]
  df_filtered = df_filtered.set_index([5])
  df_filtered = df_filtered.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
  df_range = df_filtered[start_date:end_date]
  df_groupby = df_range.groupby([4])[3].sum()
  film = df_groupby.index.values.tolist()
  footage = df_groupby.values.astype(int).tolist()
```

The code is the above.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need convert to `DatetimeIndex` column `Deadline`:

```
print (df)
   Duration Film    Deadline
0      1777    a  01/04/2018
1      1777    b  02/04/2018
2      1777    b  03/04/2018
3       942    b  04/04/2018
4       941    c  05/04/2018
```

---

```
df['Deadline'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Deadline'], dayfirst=True)

start_date= '2018-03-25'
end_date = '2018-04-04'

df = df.set_index('Deadline')[start_date:end_date]
print (df)
            Duration Film
Deadline                 
2018-04-01      1777    a
2018-04-02      1777    b
2018-04-03      1777    b
2018-04-04       942    b
```

Another solution with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Deadline'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Deadline'], dayfirst=True)

start_date= '2018-03-25'
end_date = '2018-04-04'

df = df[df['Deadline'].between(start_date, end_date)]

print (df)
   Duration Film   Deadline
0      1777    a 2018-04-01
1      1777    b 2018-04-02
2      1777    b 2018-04-03
3       942    b 2018-04-04
```